# Why can't I mount my WD My Passport USB drive?

Tags: usb-drive, external-hdd, usb-modeswitch

I got a WD My Passport 1TB external HD, ubuntu recognize it as a CD but cant mount it.
I'm usin a PC
 AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+ × 2,
 Edubuntu Presice 12.04 64-bit, 500GB HDD,
 8GB RAM, graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NV4C

Comment: Please do the following: after the drive has been connected, type `dmesg` in a terminal window and post the output using paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: If the device is recognized by **Ubuntu** as a CD-ROM, that means that the device is trying to load a (Windows) driver.  You may need a *USB modeswitch* setting for this particular brand/model of USB device.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same device running fine on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.
You may try to re-partition/format the device with an other file-system (mine is using ext3 /w TrueCrypt).